# Extract scala case class field

Tags: scala, reflection

Given the following class:
 `case class Test(id: Long, name: String) { 
   val details = Map("size" -> 54) 
}`
How do i extract `details` without instantiating the class? I Know how to extract the `id` and the `name` using Scala reflection but can't figure out how to extract what i need.

Comment: You can't extract instance members without creating an instance. No, you don't "know how to extract the `id` and the `name` using Scala reflection`, because it is impossible.

Comment: that was uncalled for. You are a douche. F. you.

Comment: Work on your attitude and maybe you'll hear less sassy comments. Maybe i thought i knew was i was talking about when actually i don't. just correct me, don't be an ass about it.

Comment: You think your comment was "sassy"? Oh well ... I would use another term. Mmmm douchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no static members in Scala. Instead, when you have data that should be statically available from arbitrary code without instantiating the enclosing class, we usually define `object`s with that data.

```
object Test {
  val Details = Map("size" -> 54)
}
case class Test(id: Long, name: String) {
  val details = Test.Details
}
```

Note the case of the literal `Details` - unlike Java, there's a convention in Scala to name constants in CamelCase, starting with an uppercase letter.